# Evaluation of $\zeta$ for integer values

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, riemann-zeta

I have recently found that $\zeta(2)$ can be found by integrating $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ from $-1$ to $1$. Since $$ \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+...)dx=2*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)$$
$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}$ has a pole in $-1$, hence it is an improper integral. This can be avoided by taking a contour that will circle around that. This can be further be extended into other positive integers by noting this formulation
$$\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx=(1-\frac{y}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{3^2}-\frac{y^3}{4^2}+...)$$
If we integrate it again from $-1$ to $1$ we get
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx)dy=\int_{-1}^{1}(1-\frac{y}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{3^2}-\frac{y^3}{4^2}+...)dy=2*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}=2(1-\frac{1}{2^3})\zeta(3)$$
Similarly, we can find values of $\zeta(k)$ for all positive integers if we can integrate
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}(\frac{1}{y_k}...\int_{0}^{y_3}(\frac{1}{y_2}\int_{0}^{y_2}(\frac{1}{y_1}\int_{0}^{y_1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}dx)dy_1)dy_2)....)dy_k$$

Is there any general way to solve the integral mentioned above?

Comment: What do you mean by solving the integral? Isn't it $$
2\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n + 1)^{k + 1} }}} ?
$$

Comment: $1.$ IMHO it is inappropriate to say that you found (the value of) $\zeta(2)$; the correct version is likely to be "you found an integral representation of $\zeta(2)$". $2.$ The nontrivial part of Zeta evaluation is that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$ (aka Basel problem), which needs more techniques than what you have already done. $3.$ There is a name for the general integral you defined, namely **polylogarithm**. One may visit Wikipedia (or other pages on this site, or Lewin's book, or whatever) to learn about properties of this function.